# occasional UnsatisfiedLinkError only on android 6.0 (api 23)

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, dlopen

spent a few hours trying to figure out why I'm getting crash reports only from  android 6.0 while loading my library.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary (Runtime.java:367)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:1076)
    at [removed].Engine.<clinit> (Engine.java:13)
```

it is a c++ library (NDK). I tried changing cmake to use PIE, but that should be on by default anyway. I can't reproduce it on the emulator either.

Comment: Make sure that the library your trying to load is supporting the target ABI.

Comment: Are you trying to load any of the internal ( not officially supported ) Android libraries? There were changes made to restrict access to them and also name changes.  The full report will include more details of why the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` can you more some more?

Comment: it's my own library @RichardCritten

Comment: I meant any dependant libraries?

Comment: build.gradle has dependancy: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1

Comment: cmake has target_link_libraries: GLESv2, EGL, log

Comment: I used scanelf to check if it built with PIE, and I am not sure, what should it output?